# Piping stream services in C#

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Suppose you have two external services:

```
public void Service1(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    // Do some stuff: it takes the input stream,
    // elaborates it and returns the result on the output stream.
}
```

and

```
public void Service2(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    // Do some stuff: it takes the input stream,
    // elaborates it and returns the result on the output stream.
}
```

and two FileStream (or two Stream in general), one to read some data from a file and the second to write the result.

I wish that the two services were called subsequentially:

- Pass the reading FileStream as input of the Service1.
- Take the output stream of the Service1 and pass it as input of the Service2
- Pass the output stream of Service2 to the writing FileStream.

My problem is in step 2. I try the following code:

```
public void CompressAndEncrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    AnonymousPipeServerStream anonymousPipeServerStream = new();
    AnonymousPipeClientStream anonymousPipeClientStream = new(anonymousPipeServerStream.GetClientHandleAsString());

    Compress(input, anonymousPipeServerStream);
    Encrypt(anonymousPipeClientStream, output);
    input.CopyTo(anonymousPipeServerStream);
}
```

but it doesn't work: it does nothing at all!

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: The stuff in service1 and service2, does it happen asynchronously? I mean, once data is available on the input stream it is processed and written to output stream? Or happens the entire processing synchronously? I mean, once the call to Service1 exits, everything is already contained in output? What is Service1 and what is Service2 in your example (Compress respectively Encrypt?)

Comment: @geraldmayr Yes, Service1 and Service2 are async. And yes, you can think of the two services as a compress service and an encryption service.

Comment: So, if they are async, what would be the purpose of `input.CopyTo(anonymousPipeServerStream)` then? Maybe it is, because according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipedirection anonymous pipes are not bi-directional?

Comment: CopyTo usually is used in Stream to start the flow.

Comment: How is the data being read from the output Stream? I had some problems getting a piping service to work because the consumer was waiting for end of line or certain number of characters which was never produced by the input stream.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins, I don't seem this is the case.  The streams are data flow: imagine something like the GZipStream. It works till the end of the stream.